Kafka UI not coming up on the machine
I am new to Kafka and setting up Kafka UI, although I have the pre-requisites setup at my end docker & docker-compose.
I have a 3 node Kafka Cluster setup at my end.
Below is the docker-compose.yml file content that I have in one of the nodes -
services:
kafka: 
  image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
  ports:
    - "8081:8081"
    - "9093:9093"
    - "9094:9094"
  environment:
    KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
    KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker,controller'
    KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_USER://kafka:9092,LISTENER_BROKER://kafka:9093,LISTENER_CONTROLLER://kafka:9094'
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'LISTENER_USER://<HOST_1_IP>:9092,LISTENER_BROKER://<HOST_1_IP>:9093'
    KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'LISTENER_USER:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_BROKER:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT'
    KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'LISTENER_CONTROLLER'
    KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'LISTENER_BROKER'
    KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@kafka:9094,2@kafka2:9094,3@kafka3:9094'
    CLUSTER_ID: 'UK52_0KiRjOJLgbi5THDqA'
  extra_hosts:
    - "kafka2:<HOST_2_IP>"
    - "kafka3:<HOST_3_IP>"

Kafka UI not accessible on this url, 404 is coming - http://<HOST1>:8081/
Please can anyone help me out on this, why the Kafka UI is not getting displayed on my machine with the above configurations? Am I missing some configs here?
Please let me know if further information is required on this.
Thanks in advance!!

Kafka is not an HTTP service. It has no UI so you cannot forward port 8081 from it

I think you are missing a docker instance that will display the UI, the cp-kafka docker image doesn't come with a builtin UI as far as I know.
Take a look at this docker-compose.yaml https://github.com/provectus/kafka-ui/blob/master/documentation/compose/kafka-ui.yaml
